# issues while using GlassFish plugin

Tags: maven, glassfish

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.readlearncode</groupId>
<artifactId>dukechat</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <primefaces.version>6.0</primefaces.version>
    <ui-lightness.version>1.0.10</ui-lightness.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <javaee-api.version>7.0</javaee-api.version>
    <tyrus.version>1.1</tyrus.version>
    <tyrus-server.version>1.13.1</tyrus-server.version>
</properties>

<name>dukechat</name>
<url>http://www.readlearncode.com</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>primefaces</id>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Standalone client/server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-server</artifactId>
        <version>${tyrus.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-client</artifactId>
        <version>${tyrus.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus</groupId>
        <artifactId>tyrus-container-grizzly</artifactId>
        <version>${tyrus.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- PrimeFaces dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>ui-lightness</artifactId>
        <version>${ui-lightness.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>dukechat</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <!-- This is needed to tell the unit tests which profile
                    we are running. -->
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <!-- GlassFish specific version of build -->
    <profile>
        <id>glassfish</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.14</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                            <zipUrlInstaller>
                                <url>http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1/release/glassfish-4.1.zip</url>
                            </zipUrlInstaller>
                        </container>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <context>/dukechat</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

I'm trying to setup a project with the above defined pom. In the plugin section GlassFish has been denoted and it is trying to download a zip from the location.

http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1/release/glassfish-4.1.zip

It has been giving me an error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.14:run (default-cli) on project dukechat: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plug
in:1.4.14:run failed: Error while expanding C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\installs\glassfish-4.1.1-web.zip
[ERROR] java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive

I've tried using some alternate url's but the same problem persists. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and solved it by changing the **cargo-maven2-plugin** version to **1.9.0**

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
```